# Android c# buttons overlap

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, mono, xamarin

I have the following problem

[image: Buttons overlap in android app]

the code im using is as follow:

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
       {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Window);

         Bla WebS = new Bla();
         foreach (var item in WebS.Fetch(null, null, null))
         {
             var Params = new Android.Widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Android.Widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 
             Android.Widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

             Button b = new Button(this);
             b.Text = item.Name;
             b.Id = Convert.ToInt16(item.ID);
             b.Click += new EventHandler(Soort_Click);
             this.AddContentView(b, Params);
         }
    }
```

I dont know what i missing here?

Comment: Could it be that you add more then one btn and that the holo btn is semi transparent?

Comment: Yes thats the plan to add more buttons but they dont need to overlap they just need to appear in sequence

Comment: Try adding setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); to your linearLayout

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px" /> already has

Comment: Sorry about that comment, don't think it will work.

Comment: While this is not an answer, I suggest you try this first in Eclipse/Android Studio in the layout editor and once you understand how layouts work then translate it to your dynamic C# code.  Its fairly basic layout stuff.

Comment: Eclipse/Android studio is not necessary, as the Xamarin Studio /Visual Studio plugin has all the necessary components.

Comment: OK, well I meant try it in the layout file first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're adding buttons to the main content area without any consideration to how they're presented.

You need to

1. add a `LinearLayout` to the `Resource.Layout.Window` content view, with a vertical orientation.
2. Get a reference to that layout with FindViewById(/*layout id*/)

   var myLayout = FindViewById(Resource.Layout.myLayout);
3. foreach button you want to add,

   layout.AddView(/* my button */);

If you can't add the LinearLayout to the `Resource.Layout.Window` content view, create it dynamically and add it to the `Resource.Layout.Window` content view before creating any of the buttons, then add the buttons to it.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

Comment: Then you have to ensure you're adding the buttons to the LinearLayout and not the main window, as you are with `this.AddContentView(b, Params);`

Answer (score 0):

```
           LinearLayout ly = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);

         Bla WebS = new Bla();
         foreach (var item in WebS.Fetch(null, null, null))
         {
             var Params = new Android.Widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Android.Widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, Android.Widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
             Button b = new Button(this);
             b.Text = item.Naam;
             b.Id = Convert.ToInt16(item.ID);
             b.Click += new EventHandler(Soort_Click);

             ly.AddView(b, Params);
         }
```

DaveDev TY Got it :)